# python list merge similar url's into list inside list

Tags: python, list, loops

i have a list of links that looks like this

the links are for site to read books

but some books have multiple parts

```
books_urls = [
    "https://example.com/read-book-22"
    "https://example.com/read-book-21.5"
    "https://example.com/read-book-21.1"
    "https://example.com/read-book-21"
    ...
    "https://example.com/read-book-5"
    "https://example.com/read-book-4"
    "https://example.com/read-book-3"
    "https://example.com/read-book-2"
    "https://example.com/read-book-1"
]
```

i want to make the books that have multiple parts lists inside this list

in this example the book 21 have more than 1 part

i want to do that so the user can enter the book number to download it and to get correct number of books inside this list

this is how i want the list to look like in the end

```
books_urls = [
    "https://example.com/read-book-22"

    ["https://example.com/read-book-21",
    "https://example.com/read-book-21.1",
    "https://example.com/read-book-21.5"]

    ...
    "https://example.com/read-book-5"
    "https://example.com/read-book-4"
    "https://example.com/read-book-3"
    "https://example.com/read-book-2"
    "https://example.com/read-book-1"]
```

Comment: You need to define what "similar" means from algorithmic perspective and then write code that would implement that algorithm

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski i think in this example it's the url's that duplicated with extra period ?

Comment: "i want to do that so the user can enter the book number to download it and to get correct number of books inside this list" – This seems like the job for a ``dict``, not a ``list``. How do you expect to find the correct link/links given a book number?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi the idea was to to get user input and enter it in list

for example

book = 5

books_urls[5 + 1]

then i noticed the 2 parts books

Answer (score 1):

If you want the user to be able to enter the book number and get a list back, I think you want to build a dictionary of lists rather than a nested list:

```
>>> flat_links = [
...     "https://example.com/read-book-22",
...     "https://example.com/read-book-21.5",
...     "https://example.com/read-book-21.1",
...     "https://example.com/read-book-21",
...     "https://example.com/read-book-5",
...     "https://example.com/read-book-4",
...     "https://example.com/read-book-3",
...     "https://example.com/read-book-2",
...     "https://example.com/read-book-1",
... ]
>>> import re
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> grouped_links = defaultdict(list)
>>> for link in flat_links:
...     grouped_links[re.match(".*read-book-(\d+).*", link).group(1)].append(link)
...
>>> grouped_links["22"]
['https://example.com/read-book-22']
>>> grouped_links["21"]
['https://example.com/read-book-21.5', 'https://example.com/read-book-21.1', 'https://example.com/read-book-21']
```